# TrueOS: Keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, trueos

The keyboard layout was set to us during installation.
`setxkbmap -query` displays layout as `us`. How to change it to `uk`?

Comment: Did my answer help in any way?

Comment: Yes. Couldn't see before as resolution on screen not correct. Thanks

Comment: Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

From [the TrueOS post-installation guide](https://www.trueos.org/handbook/postinstall.html):

- To change the keyboard layout before logging in: Click on the "Keyboard Layout" menu down at the bottom of the screen. This opens the window that allows you to pick another layout than the default.
- To change the keyboard layout while logged in: Use the `fcitx` utility.

Comment: In older versions, back when it was called PC-BSD, it was of course the _PC-BSD keyboard settings_ program (`pc-syskeyboard`) under "Preferences" on the desktop menu.